# StyleSet property ERROR: Cannot set property 'webkitTransition' of undefined

Tags: javascript, styles, transition

I am attempting to use the style.setProperty to create a sliding effect in Javascript.

Here is my code:

```
imageArray = [
    '<img src="assets/bg1.jpg"/>',
    '<img src="assets/bg2.jpg"/>',
    '<img src="assets/bg3.jpg"/>',
];

var slideWidth = 300;
var slideHeight = 420;

var currentTranslation = -slideWidth;

function init() {
    imageArray.style.webkitTransition = '-webkit-transform 1200ms';
    getArray();
}

function getArray() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    $('.inner-image').append(imageArray);
    /*not sure if this is relevant  
    imageArray.src = ary[i].media.m;*/
    }
}
```

I'm new to programming so please forgive syntax errors or inconsistencies in logic. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You got undefined error message because your `ImageArray` is an array with string in it, not a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

You can use `document.getElementById()` to get the object, or use `DOMParser` if you have to use string.